# Use Adobe Analytics to check the number of user paths between pages

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

How can I check the number of user paths from the one page to the thank you page and error pages in Adobe Analytics?

Comment: I've removed your second question.   Please limit posts to just one question at a time.

Comment: We haven't had any questions about Adobe Analytics here before.   I'm not sure any of our regulars has expertise in this area.  An answer to this may require that we attract a new expert.